# Function of velocity dependent on height in a vertical projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I have a vertical projectile motion, I want to find a function of velocity in relation of height the body is at any given moment.

From these two:
$$ v(t) = v_0 - gt \\ h(t) = v_0t - \frac{gt^2}{2}$$

I need to get:
$$v(h) = \sqrt{v_0^2 - 2gh} $$

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple question, you can think of it in this way:

What does velocity signify in this case? What does velocity signify in any case? Velocity is a measure of how quickly the particle is moving, essentially how much it has displaced by the time it took to get displaced. You could write velocity as:

$v=\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$ where ${\Delta s}$ represents the displacement it has travelled. But this doesn't work if the velocity isn't uniform, as we can see if the velocity also changes with time then the change in velocity aka the acceleration plays a role in determining its instantaneous speed. But if ${\Delta t}$ is very small the change in position (displacement) is also very small, in which case we can use the equation of velocity provided the time period is very small.
$v= \lim_{\Delta t\to0}  \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} = \frac{ds}{dt}$ where ds and dt represent very small changes in position and displacement respectively.

Now that we have got that out of the way, we need to think about what acceleration means, it is the change is velocity of course!

$a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ Now this can be rearranged as follows:

$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}*\frac{dx}{dt}$

And of course, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is nothin g but v, giving us:

$a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$

Now in this case, acceleration, the change in velocity, is nothing but g — the acceleration due to gravity. And the change in position is nothing but the change in height giving us:

$-g=v\frac{dv}{dh}$ Bear in mind that i have written -g as here gravity is retarding the ball.

Now we have $vdv=-g*dh$. We can now integrate this:

$\int_{v_0}^{v}vdv = -g \int_{0}^{h}dh$

Giving us:

$v^2-v_0^2=-2gh$ making us arrive at:

$v(h) = \sqrt{v_0^2-2gh}$

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple, so I'll just outline the proof:

1. Rearrange the first equation for $t$ and substitute $t$ into the second equation.
2. Now, you will have an equation with $h$ on the left-hand size, and two terms on the right-hand side, one with $v$ and the other with $v^2$.  Ideally, you want to *invert* this equation (to get $v$ in terms of $h$). Normally, this would be a little difficult, but since the maximum power of $v$ is 2, you can do this quite simply by [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square).

   The idea is that if you have a term that looks like $a x^2 + b x$, you can write it as: \begin{align}a x^2 + b x &= a \left(x^2 + \frac{b}{a} x  + \frac{b^2}{4a^2} -  \frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)\\ &= a \left(x + \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 -\frac{b^2}{4a}.\end{align}

   You should be able to verify this. If you complete the square correctly, you can rearrange the equation to get $v$ as a function of $h$. (You should also be able to see why $v$ must depend on the square root of a term with $h$ in it, using my above argument.)